# How can I use JavaScript/JQuery to resize the HTML of my page responsively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window, scale

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t1nnmhqh/2/) to view my example.

I am attempting to use this code in my simple website to responsively resize the HTML of the page, even as you resize your window.

Is this not possible or am I just making a simple error? The website was designed for 1360x768 (my resolution), however this code makes it look extremely wonky, and no scroll-bar is shown (unsure why).

The code to resize/scale:

```
function scalePage(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("*").each(function(){
        var width  = ($(this).width() ) / 1360;
        var height = ($(this).height()) / 768;
        $(this).css("transform", "scale("+width+","+height+")");
        $(this).css("-moz-transform", "scale("+width+","+height+")"); 
        $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+width+","+height+")");
        $(this).css("-o-transform", "scale("+width+","+height+")");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    scalePage();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    scalePage();
});
```

Comment: First of all, simply scaling the presentation of the current layout/content is not _responsive_. Additionally, if you had a good reason for doing this, you should store that logic in a function and refer to the function from your `ready` and `resize` handlers ... and store your reference to the root element .. and pass a settings object into *one* call to `css()` http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design

Comment: @KevinBoucher thank you for the advice. I've edited the post more with updated code. This time instead of only sizing the html, I resize everything. Would this be seen as a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing your page using JS is a bad idea from the get go.

Here's why:

- What if your user has JS disabled?
- What if your user has an older browser that can't render the JS quick enough?
- Each time you resize your browser the content must be re-rendered.
- Javascript should be used to add features to the site, not create them.

Secondly,

This approach is not 'responsive'. To achieve a responsive layout on your site you should use CSS to control it, As it is much faster than Javascipt/ jQuery.

A good starting point for creating responsive web pages would be this article: [2014 Guide to Responsive Web Design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/modern-field-guide-responsive-web-design). Any seasoned front-end web developer will tell you that the key to a good responsive website is to develop mobile first. This will ensure that your site will 'scale' nicely.

Thirdly,

I am going to re-iterate my point about javascript being used to add functionality, More and more do i see sites failing when i have javascript disabled or i browse on an older laptop with IE8 installed. (Although there are arguments against supporting IE8 nowadays.)